# unit testing with rollback on database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, black-box-testing

I'm just starting to understand the importance of Unit Testing in a c# environment. Now, I'm wondering how do i implement a black-box unit test that does Inserts,Deletes and updates on a database and then cleaning up the data after a successful test.

How do you actually do a process that rollbacks data inserted/updated/deleted? do you simply reset the index and remove the inserted rows? or restore the original state of the table by creating a script?

please guide me, I appreciate it. thanks!

Comment: Just for the record, you are talking about 'integration tests' here. Unit tests -by definition- don't communicate with a database. Also, take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374353/how-to-write-output-in-the-classinitialize-of-a-unit-test-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we do here in our development cycle. we always have that unit testing and load testing in our mind when ever we are developing application. So we make a column in our every datadase's table with userId or else. Then when we run Load Test or Unit test we  insert **UserId -1** in that every column, pointing that it is a load test data and **-2** in case of unit Test Data. then we have pre Define Jobs at data base end that will clean that data after some time.

Comment: hmm... you're giving me a good idea here. a trigger can instantly rollback the change if a column with this id is found.

Comment: No martin, don't use trigger for that, as it will hurt your performance. Use Sql job so that it will be deleted when you want.

Comment: Why you would not just clean up the data in the test cleanup methods? Having a job to do means you will have to be mightily careful that the data in each tests does not tread upon the data in another test because when you run multiple tests at the same time, potentially all the tests data will be in the database till the next scheduled run of the job - am i missing something here?

Comment: you are right, as i said we do keep that data for some time like 2 or 3 days to analyse and then run that job to cleanup that data. meanwhile we don't run any other test so there is no confusion at all =).

Comment: Maintaining SQL job can be a overhead. If you write the cleanup in the code itself it will be easy to re factor later also.

Comment: not it will not, normally you don't want to delete that all data right after test completes as you want to analyse that data too in order to verify that application is creating proper data in load test/ unit Test

Answer (score 3):

As long as your test is concise, and i presume it must be - for testing your DAL, why not just do the insert / update / deletes in a transaction that is rolled back once your test is complete.

Another option is to just use specific Update / Delete scripts in your test cleanup methods to roll back the exact changes that you updated / inserted to their pre-test values.

Comment: normally you don't want to delete that all data right after test completes as you want to analyse that data too in order to verify that application is creating proper data in load test/ unit Test

Comment: Analyzing the unit test data - i would have thought - would be what the test itself does by giving a success / failure result. However, if you are referring to verifying the correctness of the test data itself..thats a "who will guard the guardians" scenario..isnt it?

Comment: +1 to Have the test destroy data on start up rather than shutdown. Being able to do a manual check when the test is failing is useful.

Comment: This is still a better way to do it; it's not really a unit test so much as integration test if you need to hit the db (and even in an integration test, you should have a method in your test to query the db & check that the right info is there, not do it manually), and the test's success or failure should give you all the info you need from it. If you really want to check on your data to debug a test, you can always put in a breakpoint & check your db directly with 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;' followed by whatever query.

Answer (score 1):

I think deleting the rows in the CleanUp method should be good choice.

By this you will always be testing your deleting rows code.

Comment: so basically, do i just restore the last index in the table and that's fine?

Comment: Why to restore the index in the table? If the unit tests are independent of indexes there should not be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing a research recently and found this thread as well. Here are my findings, which might be of some help for the future readers:

- Make tests responsible for restoring the data they change. Sth like undo for the command. Tests usually know what data changes are expected, so are able to revert those in theory. This will surely involve additional work and could introduce some noise, unless it's automated, e.g you might try to keep track of the data created/updated in the test somehow generally;
- Wrap each test in transaction and revert it afterwards. Pretty much as the one above, but easier to implement with things like TransactionScope. Might be not suitable if app creates own transactions as transactions aren't composable in general and if app doesn't work with TransactionScope (there are issues with Entity Framework for example);
- Assert in some smart way on data relevant to test only. Then you won't need to cleanup anything unless there is too much data. E.g you might make your app aware of tests and set specific value to a test-only column added to every table. I've never tried that in practice;
- Create and initialize fresh database from scratch for every test;
- Use database backups to restore database to the point you need;
- Use database snapshots for the restore;
- Execute scripts to delete all the data and insert it again.

I personally use the latter and even ended up implementing a [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed) library, which does all the work for me.

Test frameworks usually do allow execute some logic before and after each test/test fixture run, which will mostlikely be needed for the ideas above. E.g for NUnit this implemented with use of [OneTimeSetUp](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/onetimesetup.html), `OneTimeTearDown`, `FixtureSetUp`, `FixtureTearDown`, `SetUp`, `TearDown` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a Mock database in place of a real database.  Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163904.aspx) that describes it.

Comment: thanks, i've been looking at this for quite some time. but i will be forced to do AOP in my layers then, something i still do not see the advantage yet other than this.

Comment: i guess it will be an over-head as you have to merge the changes every time with the duplicate one in order to sync them.